# How to manage error "Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called" when using PdfWriter from bean

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, itext

I am generating several pdf files using itext in a jsf/primefaces application. Some files generates correctly and some others don't.
After some debugging, i found that a specific line of code causes the problem.

When I call

```
writer.setPageEvent(new Footer(image));
```

where writer is of type PdfWriter. I get these error :

`[org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-96) Could not handle exception!: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called`

Ti get instanc eof Pdf Writer i use this lines of code :

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

    ec.responseReset(); // Some JSF component library or some Filter might
                        // have set some headers in the buffer beforehand.
                        // We want to get rid of them, else it may collide.
    ec.setResponseContentType(contentType); // Check
                                            // http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types
                                            // for all types. Use if
                                            // necessary
                                            // ExternalContext#getMimeType()
                                            // for auto-detection based on
                                            // filename.
    // ec.setResponseContentLength(contentLength); // Set it with the file
    // size. This header is optional. It will work if it's omitted, but the
    // download progress will be unknown.
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

    // Now you can write the InputStream of the file to the above
    // OutputStream the usual way.
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
```

I also tried to use HttpServletResponse instead :

```
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
OutputStream output = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
```

but i got the same error.

How can i solve this problem and write directly in PdfWriter ? Or do the same things without PdfWriter ?

Comment: Did you ' try/catch' `writer.setPageEvent(new Footer(image));` and see if ot actually throws an error?

Comment: *"Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called"* is not a `PdfWriter` related exception message but it sounds like an exception typically used by response-related classes of a request-response framework (like servlets). Thus, I assume an exception occurs where you assume, is then caught in some error processing code which tries to get a response writer, and that causes another a new exception the text of which you show. Please try and catch the actual exception explicitly, and tell us it's message and stack trace.